# How to do a Cross column unique constraint in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unique

How to have a Unique Constraint in Oracle-DB with two columns so that a duplicate must not occur in one or the other.

Assume this table

```
|id | A | B |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

I that a new row is not allowed to have in column "A" a value that duplicate a value from column "A" **or "B"**.

In the example above: I am allowed to add 5 to column "A" but not 1, 2, 3, or 4.

My idea was to do something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX crossTest ON test (
    SELECT t.A AS x FROM test t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.B AS x FROM test t
    )
```

but it does not work because Oracle does not accept this syntax.

The two classic approaches:

- have two unique constraints `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidxA ON test A` and `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidxB ON test B` does not work because then I could add 2 and 4 to column "A"
- have a unique constraint of two columns `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidxB ON test (A, B)` because this check only existing pairs.

*(Bonus question: it should be allowed that "A" and "B" of the same row can be equals)*

---

SQL scripts for the example

```
CREATE TABLE test (id NUMBER (10) NOT NULL, a VARCHAR2(12), b VARCHAR2(12));
INSERT INTO test (id,a,b) VALUES(1, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO test (id,a,b) VALUES(2, '3', '4');

INSERT INTO test (id,a,b) VALUES(3, '4', 'x'); -> should fail
INSERT INTO test (id,a,b) VALUES(3, '5', 'x'); -> should work
```

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think you can. You would need an index with double cardinality. You would need to produce a data set with twice as many rows...

Answer (score 2):

@Tejash's answer gave me an idea to avoid locking or serialization. You can create an auxiliary table `duet_index` to produce the extended data set with all rows. Then a simple trigger will do the trick, including your bonus question.

For example:

```
create table duet_index (
  n number,
  constraint unique uq1 (n)
);
```

And then the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger test_trg
before insert on test
for each row
begin
  insert into duet_index (n) values (:new.a);
  if (:new.a <> :new.b) then
    insert into duet_index (n) values (:new.b);
  end if;
end;
```

Please consider I'm not proficient at writing Oracle triggers. The syntax can be wrong, but the idea *should fly*.

Comment: I removed my comment.  I think this actually does avoid the concurrency issues usually present when one tries to replace Oracle constraints with triggers (because you are actually delegating to the index on `duet_index`).

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with Oracle for decades now and I don't recall having such a requirement.  It makes me nervous about your data model.

What you want to do cannot be done with a single index.  Trigger-based approaches are going to have trouble working correctly in all multi-user cases.  A materialized-view approach seems promising.

My suggestion is to create a materialized view that refreshes on commit and that contains a concatenation (`UNION ALL`) of the column A and column B values.

Here is what I mean (see comments in code for more details):

```
create table test1 ( id number not null primary key, a number, b number );

insert into test1 values ( 1, 1, 2);
insert into test1 values ( 2, 3, 4);
commit;
-- Create a snapshot to allow us to create a REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT snapshot...
create snapshot log on test1 with primary key, rowid;

-- And create that snapshot...  this will be updated when any changes to TEST1 are committed   
create materialized view test1_concat 
refresh fast on commit
as
select t1.rowid row_id, 1 as marker, t1.a concatenation from test1 t1
union all 
select t2.rowid row_id, 2 as marker, t2.b concatenation from test1 t2
-- this next bit allows a = b in single rows (i.e., bonus question)
where t2.a != t2.b;

-- Now, enforce the constraint on our snapshot to prevent cross-column duplicates
create unique index test1_concat_u1 on test1_concat ( concatenation );

-- Test #1  -- column a may equal column b without error (bonus!)
insert into test1 values ( 3, 5, 5);
commit;

-- Test #2 uniqueness enforced    
insert into test1 values ( 4, 6, 1);
-- (no error at this point)
commit;

> ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path  ORA-00001: unique
> constraint (APPS.TEST1_CONCAT_U1) violated
```

#### Drawbacks

1. There is a scalability issue here.  Oracle will synchronize on the commit.  Every *working* solution to your problem will have this drawback, I believe
2. You do not get an error until the transaction tries to commit, at which point it is impossible to correct and recover the transaction.  I believe you cannot solve this drawback in any solution without making drawback #1 much worse (i.e., without much more extensive and longer-lasting locks on your table).

Comment: Yes, this can work. I don't like the check on commit, but it's a solution. I don't know how expensive the synchronize can become on each commit, though.

Comment: The synchronization is not too expensive.  It would show up as a "enq: JI - contention" wait event.  So, if you start seeing that on reports, you know the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using `INDEX` or `CONSTRAINT`. You need a `trigger`, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
CNT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT from TEST
WHERE A = :NEW.A OR B = :NEW.A OR A = :NEW.B OR B = :NEW.B;
IF CNT > 0 THEN
raise_application_error(-20111,'This value is not allowed');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: A trigger could work but you would need to either serialize all `INSERT`s or to get full table locks during the trigger. Though not ideal, this is a workaround.

Comment: This answer should be edited to handle the necessary serialization that @TheImpaler pointed out.  As is, it fails to TXN A=>INSERT(1,1,2); TXN B=>INSERT(2,3,1); TXN A=>COMMIT; TXN B=>COMMIT;

Answer (score 1):

I suggest fixing our data model, so the values are in rows rather than columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
    type varchar2(1) check (type in ('A', 'B'),
    value varchar2(12),
    unique (value),
    unique (id, type)
);
```

The unique constraint is then easy.

Comment: You are probably right, as usual, about the data model here.  But his bonus question makes me wonder.  This data model doesn't allow rows having the same value for the same id.

Comment: For the background: each row is represent a "product" (and has more values than the named two), each product has two "codes" (a, b) for different purpose (for some products the code A and B is the same, for other not) - now the new requirement is, that the codes used by different products must be different.

Comment: @Ralph . . . Sounds like this alternate data model is a good idea.

Comment: If I have to do it from scratch it would be the best solution. But the application already exists and I hoped to find a way that is not so invasive (for the application). ... Anyway I appreciate you solution